# Quaternion offsets not consistent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamvr

## Current problem:

I'm using world space quaternion offsets to rotate a player model's hands to the player's true hands using:

```
private Quaternion GetOffsetFromAvatar(Quaternion a, Quaternion b)
{
     Quaternion _offset = a * Quaternion.Inverse(b);
     return _offset;
}
```

then applying it with:

```
public void OffsetTarget(Transform Target, Transform PlayerHand, Transform AvatarBone)
{
     /// OffsetTarget() is to be used to auto align avatar hands to player hands.

     Quaternion _offset = GetOffsetFromAvatar(PlayerHand.rotation, 
     AvatarBone.GetComponentInChildren<AvatarOffsetPoint>().transform.rotation);

Target.rotation = _offset * PlayerHand.rotation;
}
```

The expected result should allow players to change their model on the fly during runtime and the hands align correctly to the player's real hands, but when I test that, the hands face in completely different directions.

[image].

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

In the `OffsetTarget()` method; I needed to change the last line were the offset is finally applied to the avatar.

From:

```
...
     Target.rotation = _offset * PlayerHand.rotation;
}
```

To:

```
...
     Target.rotation = _offset;
}
```

Someone smarter than me, correct me if I'm wrong about the reasoning behind this answer:

I was assuming I was doing the Quaternion math in world space, but the `PlayerHand.rotation;` part of the line was actually applying the math relative to the player's hand, instead of world space by using `Quaternion.identity;`.

*I really need to stop asking a question just to answer it a few minutes later...*

Comment: As written, `GetOffsetFromAvatar` returns the global rotation from `b`, to `a`. Or, the global rotation from the `AvatarOffsetPoint` to the `PlayerHand`. I don't know what a `Target` is because the question doesn't say, but if it's the parent of the new `AvatarOffsetPoint` (or equivalent), that makes sense to me that it would work. By the way, you can just do `Target.rotation = _offset;`

Comment: For simplicity's sake, you can replace ```_offset * Quaternion.Identity``` with just ```_offset``` :)